# Ubuntu 23.04 broke Nginx

Tags: server, dependencies, nginx

I just updated to Ubuntu 23.04 and Nginx was prompting

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
```

And `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:3
```

However, I tried removing Nginx completely from the system and when I try installing it:

```
$ sudo apt install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgeoip1 but it is not installable
                Depends: liblua5.1-0 but it is not installable
                Depends: libperl5.18 (>= 5.18.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
                Recommends: passenger (< 6.0.3) but 1:6.0.18-1~bionic1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Nothing works anymore...

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt-get update`, `grep conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `ls -l /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/` to the post, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)